# Base64 decode error Last unit does not have enough valid bits

Tags: java, base64, x509certificate

I have a certificate sent to me by my vendor in a `.p7b` file. I need to extract the certificates from it. So I run this on my cmd:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -outform PEM -in in.p7b -print_certs > cer_bundle.cer
```

I open up `cer_bundle.cer` and see three certificates. First two seem fine. The final certificate when put thru `Base64.getDecoder().decode(myCert)` throws up an error like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits\n\tat 
java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:734)\n\tat 
java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)\n\tat 
java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)\n\t
...
```

I then take contents of the cert and do this on my terminal

```
CERT=MIIFDj...
base64 --decode <<< $CERT
```

and I see an output on my console with no errors.

What's going on in java's Base64 decoder?

Comment: Can you share the last few (maybe 8) characters of the base64 encoded data?

Comment: @Erik here u go: `wt35Lcw=`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Base 64 encoding uses four characters to encode three bytes, so the length should be a multiple of four characters. If the input is a multiple of three bytes no padding is needed, otherwise `=` will be added. There will be one or two "remainder" bytes.

- With one "remainder" byte, the trailing four chars are `XY==` where `X` encodes six bits and `Y` encodes two bits.
- With two "remainder" bytes the trailing four chars are `XYZ=` where `X` encodes six bits, `Y` encodes two bits of the first byte and four bits of the second byte while `Z` encodes four bits of the second byte.

The error your getting indicates that the last four characters are essentially `X===` (the `=` may be omitted) which makes no sense in base 64 encoding.

Comment: I did a thorough letter by letter checking and turns out somewhere I missed a character while removing the new lines - no wonder there were "fewer" bits to decode